# SQL Based User Timesheet

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table where I have been gathering user's clock in, clock out times and this gets displayed onto a calendar no problem.  However, now I would like to see what hours all users are working.

Every time a user Clocks In, a new record is created.  Every time a user clocks out, a new record is created also.

My SQL code below allows me to bring up Clock In and Clock Out times:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DateTime;
DECLARE @EndDate DateTime;
DECLARE @AssumedShiftStartTime DateTime;
DECLARE @AssumedShiftEndTime DateTime;
DECLARE @EmployeeName nvarchar(200);
DECLARE @ShiftStart DateTime
DECLARE @ShiftEnd DateTime


-- Date format: YYYY-MM-DD
SET @StartDate = '2014-07-01 00:00:00'
SET @EndDate = DATEADD (DAY, 1, @StartDate);  -- Add one day
SET @AssumedShiftEndTime = '18:00:00'
SET @AssumedShiftStartTime = '09:00:00'
SET @EmployeeName = 'Paul';

--------------  Get Clock IN / OUT TIMES -----------------
SELECT EmployeeAttendance.LastUpdate, EmployeeAttendance.ClockInTime, EmployeeAttendance.ClockOutTime
FROM            EmployeeAttendance INNER JOIN
                         Membership ON EmployeeAttendance.UserId = Membership.UserId

WHERE EmployeeAttendance.LastUpdate >= @StartDate AND EmployeeAttendance.LastUpdate <= @EndDate
AND Membership.Username = @EmployeeName
```

Which gives the following results:

```
    LastUpdate                 ClockInTime                 ClockOutTime
    2014-07-01 08:48:08.650    2014-07-01 08:48:08.650     NULL    
    2014-07-01 18:04:39.943    NULL                        2014-07-01 18:04:39.923
    2014-07-02 08:48:08.680    2014-07-01 09:00:08.340     NULL    
    2014-07-02 18:04:39.343    NULL                        2014-07-01 18:00:39.623
    2014-07-03 08:48:08.620    2014-07-01 08:58:08.860     NULL    
    2014-07-03 18:04:39.455    NULL                        2014-07-01 18:05:39.985
```

What I am really trying to achieve is something that returns the following results.

EDIT: Where the results return a null, I want to use @AssumedShiftStartTime or @AssumedShiftEndTime to allow a result to be caluclated for total hours but gets difficult because two seperate records are recorded for Clock In and Clock Out:

```
DATE          CLOCK-IN-TIME    CLOCK-OUT-TIME   TOTAL-HOURS
2014-07-01    08:49            18:04            9 Hours 15 Mins
2014-07-02    09:00            18:00            9 Hours 00 Mins
2014-07-03    08:58            18:05            9 Hours 07 Mins


Total-This-Month
27 Hours 15 Mins
```

EDIT:  Thank you [Sean Lange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange) for your help.  After applying the help from your reply I get the following output which shows two rows account for Clock In and Clock Out.  I am trying to determine how would be the best way to get the results for a single day, calculate total hours, merge next two and calculate hours etc.  I think this is more complicated than it needs to be and maybe time for a SQL logic recode?

```
2014-07-01 08:48:08.650 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-01 18:04:39.923 NULL    NULL
2014-07-02 08:54:03.483 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-02 17:09:34.940 NULL    NULL
2014-07-03 08:48:01.070 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-03 18:12:11.487 NULL    NULL
2014-07-04 08:48:07.983 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-04 18:07:09.390 NULL    NULL
2014-07-05 08:56:24.410 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-05 14:19:12.800 NULL    NULL
2014-07-08 08:44:56.727 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-08 18:15:12.143 NULL    NULL
2014-07-09 08:46:15.103 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-09 17:10:46.327 NULL    NULL
2014-07-10 08:57:14.733 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-10 18:10:37.897 NULL    NULL
2014-07-11 08:52:10.783 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-11 18:08:58.580 NULL    NULL
2014-07-12 08:56:20.073 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-12 14:15:44.103 NULL    NULL
2014-07-15 08:47:04.330 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-15 18:10:05.800 NULL    NULL
2014-07-16 08:56:34.490 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-16 17:05:06.627 NULL    NULL
2014-07-17 08:46:37.263 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-17 18:06:08.840 NULL    NULL
2014-07-18 08:52:56.200 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-18 18:11:25.750 NULL    NULL
2014-07-19 08:54:36.277 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-19 14:15:09.620 NULL    NULL
2014-07-22 08:56:30.623 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-22 16:03:00.653 NULL    NULL
2014-07-23 08:49:53.687 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-23 17:07:37.943 NULL    NULL
2014-07-24 08:52:08.690 NULL    NULL    NULL
2014-07-25 08:57:13.477 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-25 18:09:01.793 NULL    NULL
2014-07-26 08:53:42.597 NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2014-07-26 14:03:21.063 NULL    NULL
```

Any help would be gratefully accepted.

Thank you

Comment: Can you create a sql fiddle to set this up? You have some results from your current query but the rows don't at all match what you stated you want as output. How do you handle NULL for a time? Do you have some default?

Comment: I stripped out some of the irrelevant SQL and not all the declares are needed.  I will edit this out right now.   What I am trying to achieve is to get something that looks like the final code segment in my question.

Comment: OK. Then I assume the challenge is getting the TotalHours column? You can do this with DATEDIFF. First use minutes and mod 60 to get the minutes. Then use hours to get hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we make up some test data:

```
DECLARE @TimeSheet TABLE
(
    EmpId INT,
    LastUpdate DATETIME,
    ClockInTime DATETIME,
    ClockOutTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @TimeSheet
VALUES
(201, '2014-07-01 08:48:08.650',    '2014-07-01 08:48:08.650'   ,NULL                     ),    
(201, '2014-07-01 18:04:39.943',    NULL                        ,'2014-07-01 18:04:39.923'),
(201, '2014-07-02 08:48:08.680',    '2014-07-01 09:00:08.340'   ,NULL                     ),
(201, '2014-07-02 18:04:39.343',    NULL                        ,'2014-07-01 18:00:39.623'),
(201, '2014-07-03 08:48:08.620',    '2014-07-01 08:58:08.860'   ,NULL                     ),
(201, '2014-07-03 18:04:39.455',    NULL                        ,'2014-07-01 18:05:39.985'),
(110, '2014-07-01 08:48:08.650',    '2014-07-01 06:48:08.650'   ,NULL                     ),    
(110, '2014-07-01 18:04:39.943',    NULL                        ,'2014-07-01 14:01:39.923'),
(110, '2014-07-02 08:48:08.680',    '2014-07-01 07:10:08.340'   ,NULL                     ),
(110, '2014-07-02 18:04:39.343',    NULL                        ,'2014-07-01 14:00:39.623'),
(110, '2014-07-03 08:48:08.620',    '2014-07-01 06:58:58.860'   ,NULL                     ),
(110, '2014-07-03 18:04:39.455',    NULL                        ,'2014-07-01 14:01:39.985');
```

Now lets create a CTE to number our data:

```
WITH TimeRows AS
(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpId, CAST(LastUpdate AS DATE) ORDER BY LastUpdate) RN
    FROM @TimeSheet
)
```

Now we query the CTE against itself to find our clockin and clockout times:

```
SELECT T1.EmpId,
    T1.ClockInTime,
    T2.ClockOutTime,
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, T1.ClockInTime, T2.ClockOutTime) AS DHour,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, T1.ClockInTime, T2.ClockOutTime) % 60 AS DMinutes
FROM TimeRows T1
INNER JOIN TimeRows T2
    ON T2.EmpId = T1.EmpId
    AND T2.RN = T1.RN + 1
    AND CAST(T2.LastUpdate AS DATE) = CAST(T1.LastUpdate AS DATE)
```

Here is the output:

```
EmpId   ClockInTime ClockOutTime    DHour   DMinutes
110 2014-07-01 06:48:08.650 2014-07-01 14:01:39.923 8   13
110 2014-07-01 07:10:08.340 2014-07-01 14:00:39.623 7   50
110 2014-07-01 06:58:58.860 2014-07-01 14:01:39.987 8   3
201 2014-07-01 08:48:08.650 2014-07-01 18:04:39.923 10  16
201 2014-07-01 09:00:08.340 2014-07-01 18:00:39.623 9   0
201 2014-07-01 08:58:08.860 2014-07-01 18:05:39.987 10  7
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.  Still not 100% what this SQL does but have a general idea and will work it out.  Something I couldnt have done myself, thanks again to yours and other answers here.  Both have really helped.

Comment: 8 years later and this post was still very helpful for me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this help?

```
declare @Times table(ClockIn datetime, ClockOut datetime)

insert @Times
select '2014-07-01 08:49', '2014-07-01 18:04' union all
select '2014-07-01 09:00', '2014-07-01 18:00'

select *
    , datediff(hour, ClockIn, ClockOut) - case when datediff(minute, ClockIn, ClockOut) % 60 > 0 then 1 else 0 end as MyHours
    ,datediff(minute, ClockIn, ClockOut) % 60 as MyMinutes
from @Times
```

Comment: that's perfect thank you. My next question, how would I populate @Times table from the results of the first select statement in my question?

Comment: You don't need to. I just declared that as a table variable to demonstrate the technique. Just apply the logic to your original query.

Comment: I understand and this works but the Clock In and the clock Out are different rows (two rows for a single clock in/ clock out pair?).  I know this may not be efficient.  Maybe I should re-code to use ClockIn1, ClockOut1, ClockIn2, ClockOut2, ClockIn3, ClockOut3 etc instead of a different row for each.

Comment: Well unless you can post some consumable ddl and sample data there is not much I can do to help. A sql fiddle would make short work of this.

Comment: I understand, I have just posted my output I get after running your datediff code which may help explain what I am trying to achieve.  I will try and create some sql to build up some sample data.  Thank you for your time, this is much appreciated and heading in a better direction now.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  A combination of yours and the answer below has solved this problem perfectly.